# website not pointing to magento hosting

Tags: .htaccess, magento, server, magento-1.9, directadmin

I have a magento multi store site. And I have some websites integrated it to the same. Today I have added another website,

> Created website, store, store view in magento admin panel. changed
>   base url, and secured url, and edited htaccess file

also. Still

> my website is not pointing to my magento,
>
> It showing the default home screen of server.

When I checked all I could understand is that

> newly added domain is not picking up this htaccess file, instead it
>   create a new folder and new .htacces file for itself.

I am using direct admin for server management.

Why is it so? Can any one give me a solution?

Comment: what is  url of your  site ?

Comment: hi, its http://brandgallery.in/

Comment: upload your website into the public_html directory

Comment: But it is a multi store magento website, Already I have the file system uploaded in my directory.  And edited .htaccess file also.

Comment: Please check your index.php file. Is there any code added to pointing to specific domain?

Comment: No, it is default magenot index.php file. And some other domains are also working with the same account, and those are working perfectly.

Comment: If all setting are fine from your side, i suggest to clear cache and Reindex everything.

Comment: I cleared it. Still no result. :(

Comment: What are your changes in the .htaccess?

Comment: `SetEnvIf Host www\.domain\.in MAGE_RUN_CODE=domain_in
SetEnvIf Host www\.domain\.in MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
SetEnvIf Host ^domain\.in MAGE_RUN_CODE=domain_in
SetEnvIf Host ^domain\.in MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website`

this is the htaccess code i have added. Actually the problem is that newly added domain is not picking up this htaccess file, instead it create a new folder and new .htacces file for itself.